# Проверка при вводе адреса доставки не находит по названиям отелей

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

помогите пожалуйста, мне нужно чтобы готовое решение из песочницы - [Проверка при вводе адреса доставки](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation) находила адрес по названию гостиницы или отеля, а то у меня находит только по координатам или адресу с такими настройками

ymaps.geocode(request, {kind: 'house'}, {provider: 'yandex#search'})

это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Обратное геокодирование возможно использовать.
Но, в твое случае логично будет использовать свой БД гостиниц с координатами, т.е. сделаешь свой input text и при вводе в нее, будет искать по БД гостиниц и делать центрирование карты по координатам гостиниц.